# Use a string(Varchar2) of number as number

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a existing procedure that accepts input in the form of varchar2.
This input field is actually a set of numbers comma separated e.g. '1,2,3' or '2,3' etc.

Now inside the procedure, want to use these numbers in a IN clause as in:

```
PROCEDURE SAVE_SETTING (p_category_list   IN VARCHAR2)
IS

BEGIN


UPDATE my_table
SET status = 'ACTIVE'
  WHERE category_id IN ( p_category_list );

END;
```

Now the category_id column of my_table is of Number datatype.
So I have to convert p_category_list  into a set of numbers to make the query effectively:

```
 UPDATE my_table
    SET status = 'ACTIVE'
      WHERE category_id IN ( 1,2,3);
```

Instead of

```
 UPDATE my_table
    SET status = 'ACTIVE'
      WHERE category_id IN ( '1,2,3');
```

I donot want to use Dynamic sql (Execute Immediate)

Any help in achieving this?

Comment: Can your p_category_list provide input value itself as '1','2','3'?

Comment: I cannot change the input in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi This is just an example how you can effectively use the update.

SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  p_list VARCHAR2(100);
  my_list dbms_sql.number_table;
BEGIN
  p_list:=('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');             --Your Input
  SELECT regexp_substr(p_list,'[^,]+', 1, level) bulk collect -- used to collect each input as number
  INTO my_list
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(p_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
  forall i IN my_list.first..my_list.last
  UPDATE emp SET mgr = my_list(i) WHERE deptno = 10;--update statement
  dbms_output.put_line('working');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) will help you here:

```
PROCEDURE SAVE_SETTING (p_category_list   IN VARCHAR2)
IS

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE my_table
                       SET status = ''ACTIVE''
                         WHERE category_id IN ( ' || p_category_list || ' )';

END;
```

Comment: I know its easy using dynamic sql, but I don't want to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:-
( This helps in using comma-separated list as 'in' clause in stored procedure. No need of dynamic query)

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET status = 'ACTIVE'
   WHERE category_id in 
   (select ltrim(rtrim(regexp_substr(p_category_list,'[^,]+', 1, level)))   
    from dual connect by ltrim(rtrim(regexp_substr(p_category_list, '[^,]+', 1, level)))    
  is not null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use dynamic SQL, you can just use `like`:

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET status = 'ACTIVE'
  WHERE ',' || p_category_list || ',' like '%,' || category_id || ',%';
```

Note the extra delimiters on each side to ensure that `1` doesn't match `10`.

Answer (score 0):

i would write a little function which returns a VARRAY by p_category_list, in the function separate p_category_list in the way what you want and filter by this instead of p_category_list  in the UPDATE